# Incorrect routing with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a routing problem with a laravel application.

I have the following route:

```
Route::get('home', array

       ('as' => 'home', 
        'uses' => 'HomeController@getHome'

       ));
```

which leads to the following url:

192.168.2.22/laravel/public/home

all is fine with this.

Then I have a second route like this:

```
Route::get('users/{id?}', function($id) {


   $user = Users::find($id);

return View::make('Account.profile')->with('user', $user);
});
```

which leads to the following url:

192.168.2.22/laravel/public/users/1

Now when I click the Home link again from this page I get :

192.168.2.22/laravel/public/users/home

which of course gives me an error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what is the link in your view you are clicking? sounds like you're clicking on a link with a relative path

Comment: this is the link :  <a class="navbar-brand" href="home">home</a>

Comment: use either the Route:: facade or the short route_to functions to create save routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using either `{{ URL::to('home') }}` (the route's URL) or `{{ URL::route('home') }}` (the route's name) as your link's `href` attribute will solve this.

i.e.:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ URL::route('home') }}">home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use handmade links...

do it like this:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo link_to_route("home");?>">home</a>
```

this will work if you use php OR blade but i would recommend to do it like that for blade:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{link_to_route("home")}}">home</a>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get an explanation for the downvote?

Comment: @ceejayoz actually no it wasn't since you can use <?php .... ?> in a blade template!

Comment: @ITroubs You can, but probably shouldn't. I gave you a +1 after you added the blade version.

Comment: I just put it there since not everyone is working with blade AND if you are working with a pure php templating approach you can use the first string AND if you are working with blade you can too although the balde version is more readable. in the end the compiled view will look the same either way...

Comment: instead of showing the word : HOME         it now says :http://192.168.2.22/laravel/public/home"     and when i click the link it is still nog working

Comment: actually that is exactly what you need an looking at your question which states the following: `witch leads to the following url:192.168.2.22/laravel/public/home all is fine with this.` that even shows that it SHOULD work

Answer (score 0):

Use some Laravel Helpers to be sure your links are always valid:

```
echo link_to_route('route.name', $title, $parameters = array(), $attributes = array());
```